# Relative source requests in Manychat Application json file

Tags: json, facebook

How to write json Manychat application file, with setup feature like in Google Sheets Manychat app?
In this Google Sheets Manychat app, at setup we select Spreadsheet, then we select Worksheet. Worksheet is relative to Spreadsheet. How to write similar functionality in json Manychat application file? Or maybe it not possible to regular users?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible at the moment since Manychat doesn't provide an onchange event. All list resources are loaded alongside the form.

You could separate them in two actions, one for the spreadsheet selection and one for the sheet selection.